# PowerShell script to process cube on Azure - connection issue

Tags: powershell, azure, ssas, cube

I am trying to process cube on Azure with Powershell script. Have this kind of code:

```
# PowerShell code 
# Connect to a connection to get TenantId and SubscriptionId
$Connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
$TenantId = $Connection.TenantId
$SubscriptionId = $Connection.SubscriptionId

# Get the service principal credentials connected to the automation account. 
#$null = $SPCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "Samcred"

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

# Select the correct subscription
Write-Output "Selecting subscription '$($SubscriptionId)'."
$null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionId

# Get variable values
$DatabaseName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'DatabaseName'
$AnalysisServerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'AnalysisServerName'

# Show info before processing (for testing/logging purpose only)
Write-Output "Processing $($DatabaseName) on $($AnalysisServerName)"

#Process database
$null = Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename $DatabaseName -server $AnalysisServerName -RefreshType "Full" -Credential $SPCredential 

# Show done when finished (for testing/logging purpose only)
Write-Output "Done"
```

After execution there is connection error:

```
Invoke-ProcessASDatabase : Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not 
available.
At line:46 char:9
+ $null = Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -databasename $DatabaseName -server  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ProcessASDatabase], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ProcessASDatabase
```

Using Microsoft SQL Analysis Server (version 15.0.0.52). 
Somehow there is need again to put account and password, which I already done.

Comment: the value $SPCredential is null, I think this is the reason you get the error log.